# Jquery simplyscroll plugin for auto content scrolling is work with static but with ng-repeat not working

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, html

Jquery simplyscroll plugin for auto content scrolling work with static content
but when I am adding ng-repeat inside then it is not working.

If anyone have other solution in angular for auto vertical content scroller,then please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [angular-scroll-glue](https://github.com/Luegg/angularjs-scroll-glue)

you just need to add `scroll-glue` directive

```
<div scroll-glue>
    <!-- Content here will be "scroll-glued". -->
</div>
```

you can check [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/wxTyp7PpyxJOHSlUumVC?p=preview) for the same by angular-scroll-glue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and here was how I resolved it.

I used the $timeout service to ensure that the DOM was loaded before initializing the scroller:

```
        $timeout(function() {
          $("#scroller").simplyScroll({
            orientation: 'vertical',
            customClass: 'vert',
            frameRate: 20,
            speed: 3
          });
        }, 0, false);
```

I also had to use the `vert` class and used a modified version of the example CSS provided:

```
.vert {
  height: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

/* Clip DIV */
.vert .simply-scroll-clip 
  height: 400px;
}

/* Explicitly set height/width of each list item */
.vert .simply-scroll-list li {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

I realized that the most important bit is that you have to set an explicit height for each `li` item.

Here is the original CSS for the `vert` class if you want to start from the example they had for the vertical scroller:

http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/vertical.html